In Chromium, how do I avoid long delays to user input when another tab is very busy?
The problem discussed here only occurs on my computers if “Use hardware acceleration if available” is switched on.  But I need that for Google Maps 3D.  I do not have expensive GPUs, only on-board chips on my laptops.
For more than a year now, I observe unacceptable delays to user interaction in the Chromium browser.  If I stream a video, or open a web app that executes CPU-intensive JavaScript, Chromium may enter something I call “priority mode” in the following.
When in priority mode, other tabs seem to go to sleep.  This is sensible behavior if one could wake one of them up within a couple of milliseconds, but I observe one to three seconds of delay before Chromium reacts to user input.
For instance, I open a Wikipedia page in another tab – the video is still playing in the first tab – and when I turn the mouse wheel, it takes two seconds before the wiki page starts scrolling.  Then, I can interact with the wiki page normally without delays until I make a significantly long pause.  Then, the wiki tab has gone into sleep again.
I don’t know yet when Chromium enters priority mode.  A busy tab like a streaming video or intensive JavaScript processing is a precondition, though.  If I close all such tabs, Chromium is never in priority mode.  However, it may also not be if such tabs are active.
Still, priority mode is well-reproducible on my systems.  I have two very different laptops that run the same Ubuntu 22.04 config.  Both exhibit this behavior.

Sounds like the computer is under-powered for what you are trying to do.

Definitively not because everything is working smoothly except for the delays, which are obviously avoidable.
